# How to arrange the height of divs in percentage, without scroll bars, in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to make a content box to be responsive. i can set the width of Div s in percentage (eg:30%, 50%). But when i am setting height in percentage, its not working.
I want to make 3 divs of my page in a specefic %of my page.

```css
.top
{
 height:250px;
     /*height:28%;*/
 background-color:#dad8c3;
 width:100%;
 
}
.body_part{
 width:100%;
 background-color:#9CC;
 
 height:560px;
    /*height:60%;*/
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg,#e4e0dd,white,#e4e0dd ); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg,#e4e0dd,white,#e4e0dd); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg,#e4e0dd,white, #e4e0dd); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg,#e4e0dd,white, #e4e0dd); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
 
}
.footer_part{

 background-color:#6c5067;
 width:100%;
    height:97px;
 /*height:12% !important;*/
 
}
html,body{
 background-image:url(../images/moment%20a.jpg);
 height:100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 top">
  <div class="container"></div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 body_part">
   <div class="container"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class=" col-lg-12 footer_part">
  <div class="container"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: check-out the bootstrap grid docs; you got your markup messed up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [viewport percentage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)  unit to do that:

```css
html,
body, body > div {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.top {
  height: 28vh;
  background-color: #dad8c3;
}
.body_part{
  background-color: #9CC;
  height: 60vh;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, #e4e0dd, white, #e4e0dd);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg, #e4e0dd, white, #e4e0dd);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, #e4e0dd, white, #e4e0dd);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #e4e0dd, white, #e4e0dd);
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
.footer_part {
  background-color: #6c5067;
  height:12vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 top">
    <div class="container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 body_part">
    <div class="container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col-lg-12 footer_part">
    <div class="container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, its working, But i want to avoid the scrolling bar when i minimize the page's height. now when i make this window small, i cannot see footer part.

Comment: I see no scroll bars (in chrome and firefox), I set the margin at 0 of all 3 divs, and the footer height should always be 12% of the page height.

Comment: thanx for ur comment dude, i tried so. there is no scroll bar in large screen s. but when it coming to small screen scroll bar is coming for height. but there is no scroll bar for width, as it is a bootstrap page.any method to solve this? thanx